# Memory leak when I using io_service::run

Tags: c++, boost, memory-leaks, boost-asio

I am trying to write my socket class (code below). 
At last everything works:reconnection, connection, message send, message receive

But I noticed memory leak when I repeat TCPSocketBody::Connect(const std::string &adress, const std::string &port) if for example host is unreachable. Size of my application is growing.

I discovered that when I remove line:

```
thread_io_service = boost::thread(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &io_service_global));
```

the problem disappears. But I need this line. What I am doing wrong?
I checked from command line number of thread in my application and it always is 1 or 2.

```
#include "TCPSocketBody.h"

TCPSocketBody::TCPSocketBody() : socket_(io_service_global),
                                 resolver(io_service_global),
                                 connected(false),
                                 expectedMessage(0)
{

}

void TCPSocketBody::Close()
{
  io_service_global.post(boost::bind(&TCPSocketBody::DoClose, this));
}

void TCPSocketBody::Connect(const std::string &adress, const std::string &port)
{
    io_service_global.reset();
    iterator = resolver.resolve({adress, port});

     boost::asio::async_connect(socket_, iterator,
           boost::bind(&TCPSocketBody::HandleConnect, this,
           boost::asio::placeholders::error));


     socket_.set_option(boost::asio::ip::tcp::no_delay(true));

     thread_io_service = boost::thread(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &io_service_global));

}

void TCPSocketBody::HandleConnect(const boost::system::error_code& error)
{
  if (!error)
  {           
      connected = true;

      boost::asio::async_read(socket_,
         boost::asio::buffer(data_to_read, MessageCoder::BufferSize()), boost::asio::transfer_all(),
         boost::bind(&TCPSocketBody::HandleReadHeader, this,
           boost::asio::placeholders::error));

  } else
  {
        Close();
  }
}

void TCPSocketBody::HandleReadHeader(const boost::system::error_code& error)
{
    expectedMessage = MessageCoder::HeaderToVal(data_to_read);

    if (expectedMessage > MessageCoder::MaxMessageSize())
    {
       expectedMessage = 0;
       Close();
    } else
    {
        boost::asio::async_read(socket_,
           boost::asio::buffer(data_to_read, expectedMessage), boost::asio::transfer_all(),
           boost::bind(&TCPSocketBody::HandleReadMessage, this,
             boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    }
}

void TCPSocketBody::HandleReadMessage(const boost::system::error_code& error)
{
    expectedMessage = 0;        

    boost::asio::async_read(socket_,
       boost::asio::buffer(data_to_read, MessageCoder::BufferSize()), boost::asio::transfer_all(),
       boost::bind(&TCPSocketBody::HandleReadHeader, this,
         boost::asio::placeholders::error));
}

void TCPSocketBody::WriteMessage(char *dataToSend)
{
    io_service_global.post(boost::bind(&TCPSocketBody::Write, this, dataToSend));
}

void TCPSocketBody::Write(char *dataToSend)
{
    data = dataToSend;

    boost::asio::async_write(socket_,
        boost::asio::buffer(data, std::strlen(data)),
        boost::bind(&TCPSocketBody::HandleWrite, this,
          boost::asio::placeholders::error));

}

void TCPSocketBody::HandleWrite(const boost::system::error_code& error)
{
  if (!error)
  {

  }
  else
  {
        Close();
  }
}

void TCPSocketBody::DoClose()
{
  socket_.close();
  connected = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without the header file, it is hard to be certain.  I suspect that thread_io_service is a member variable.  A second call to 'Connect' will overwrite the existing value without destroying the object.  Any memory allocated within the object will be leaked.

Perhaps try making a std::vector of thread_io_service and push_back each new thread on the connect call. The vector will destroy the contained objects when it gets destructed.

Valgrind can likely pinpoint the issue with more detail.

Comment: Your welcome.  If my answer was helpful, please 'accept' it.  I'm trying to build my reputation and your help is appreciated.